# Split layout for HTML screen, content below not visible

Tags: html, css, split-screen

I am trying to create a Split Layout using https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/25/split-layout/
However, I am unable to see the contents below the split view. I am able to scroll but cannot see contents of element id "services". I am not posting the CSS in order to avoid making it readable. The CSS can be found on the link above. Thank you.

```
<div id="splitlayout" class="splitlayout">
      <div class="intro">
        <div class="side side-left">
          <header class="codropsheader clearfix">
            <span>Blueprint <span class="bp-icon bp-icon-about" data-content="The Blueprints are a collection of basic and minimal website concepts, components, plugins and layouts with minimal style for easy adaption and usage, or simply for inspiration."></span></span>
            <h1>Split Layout</h1>
            <nav>
              <a href="http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/OnScrollEffectLayout/" class="bp-icon bp-icon-prev" data-info="previous Blueprint"><span>Previous Blueprint</span></a>
              <!--a href="" class="bp-icon bp-icon-next" data-info="next Blueprint"><span>Next Blueprint</span></a-->
              <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=16693" class="bp-icon bp-icon-drop" data-info="back to the Codrops article"><span>back to the Codrops article</span></a>
              <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/category/blueprints/" class="bp-icon bp-icon-archive" data-info="Blueprints archive"><span>Go to the archive</span></a>
            </nav>
            <div class="demos">
              <a class="current" href="index.html">Effect 1</a>
              <a href="index2.html">Effect 2</a>
            </div>
          </header>
          <div class="intro-content">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img class="img-fluid" src ={% static "images/teacher-4.png" %} alt="alternative">
          </div> 
            <h1><span>Toby Blue </span><span>Web Designer</span></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="side side-right">
          <div class="intro-content">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img class="img-fluid" src ={% static "images/student-2.png" %} alt="alternative">
          </div> 
            <h1><span>Amy White </span><span>Web Developer</span></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /intro -->
      <div class="page page-right">
        <div class="page-inner">
          <section>
           </section>
          <section>
            </section>
          <section>
           </section>
          <section>
           </section>
          <section>
            </section>
        </div><!-- /page-inner -->
      </div><!-- /page-right -->
      <div class="page page-left">
        <div class="page-inner">
          <section>
              </section>
          <section>
           </section>
          <section>
            </section>
          <section>
            </section>
        </div><!-- /page-inner -->
      </div><!-- /page-left -->
      <a href="#" class="back back-right" title="back to intro">&rarr;</a>
      <a href="#" class="back back-left" title="back to intro">&larr;</a>
    </div><!-- /splitlayout -->
  
<!-- Services -->
<div id="services" class="cards-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2>Create an eQuiz and schedule it in less than 1 minute.</h2>
                <p class="p-heading p-large">Now all you need are a few clicks and your students get an eQuiz</p>
            </div> <!-- end of col -->
        </div> <!-- end of row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <!-- Card -->
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-image" src ={% static "images/employee.svg" %} alt="alternative">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Pick Difficulty & Topic</h4>
                        <p>The questions and quiz comes with a level of difficulty and spread across all chapters </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of card -->

                <!-- Card -->
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-image" src ={% static "images/quiz-icon.svg" %} alt="alternative">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Random Q&A</h4>
                        <p>Students get random questions and options from our huge pool of questions</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of card -->

                <!-- Card -->
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-image" src ={% static "images/quiz-2.svg" %} alt="alternative">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Different Options</h4>
                        <p> You can test students on MCQ, True/False & Essay Type Questions </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of card -->
                
            </div> <!-- end of col -->
        </div> <!-- end of row -->
    </div> <!-- end of container -->
</div> <!-- end of cards-1 -->
<!-- end of services -->
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Make it as easy for us to help you by putting all the code in one spot that replicates the issues. Ideally only provide enough code to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `position: fixed;` on `.side` to `position: absolute;`.

```
.side {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

*Check it in action on Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/YzpWvaZ*